# Strategies for mitigating or dealing with bad or inaccurate reviews on product/service websites

Tags: user-behavior, customer-experience, social-proof

I have seen questions regarding fake reviews that give glowing appraisals for products or services which are paid for by the companies that provide those products/services (or by the marketing/PR company that they paid), and this is one of the issues with review systems.

What about the opposite scenario of people who deliberately seek to damage the reputation of their competitors by writing bad reviews? Is it actually just as easy to spot a damaging review that is either not from a genuine customer or by someone who is exaggerating the facts because they want to vent after their expectations were not met? What are the strategies that can be used to reduce the impact of these types of reviews?

On a related topic, do 'bad' reviews really have the effect and impact intended on review systems? I saw an [interesting question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69165/is-it-normal-for-menus-to-be-priced-in-grams-in-venice-italy) about prices at an overseas restaurant in another StackExchange site where someone thought they were being overcharged, and the restaurant in question didn't have a very good rating yet people still don't seem to consider checking the ratings (or if they did it didn't prevent them from visiting for whatever reason).

Answer (score 3):

When you got a bad review first apologies for you could't exceed their expectations.  Then genuinely respond to resolve their issue.  This can turn into your advantage because people will see how much you concern and willing to help.

When it comes to people who deliberately seek to damage the reputation of their competitors; ask questions like, when you get our service? May I know your invoice ID to find out more about your complain? If you sent your payment details, we would like to give full refund etc. If they are fake customers they couldn't be able to proceed anymore.

always be

- polite
- grateful for their time and the review
- don't defend yourself

That's what I would do. Hope this is help.

Comment: +1 Do you find that people who provide bad reviews and then don't respond to your questions is then seen by the rest of the users as just a trouble maker? Do you find that if you respond to bad reviews then people try to take advantage of any refunds and offers that you provide? Do you have any actual examples that help to illustrate the effectiveness of the strategies that you mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. When I read the review and I can understand customer care is superb but something wrong with the reviewer. 

If you are truly providing service it's very rare that people take advantage of this. They will feel more secure to do business or get services from you.   

Meantime I couldn't find exact scenario like this but if you search on websites like tripadviser you may find lot of samples. 

Also these links might helpful for you [link](https://www.groovehq.com/support/deal-with-bad-online-reviews)

Comment: The link that you provided has lots of good information. If you can summarize it briefly in your answer I would be happy to accept it if no one else has anything further to add. Thanks.